# Dynamic password generation in PHP

Tags: php, cakephp

In php how can i generate a strong password using email ,current time etc.It should be atleast 45 character length.

whether `generate_password();` is a good one?

Comment: Sidenote: Use CRYPT_BLOWFISH or PHP 5.5's `password_hash()` function for password storage.

Comment: What would you consider a strong password? At least 16 characters? Comprehensive 8?

Answer (score -1):

use php's built in `password_hash()`. don't roll your own password hashing unless you are an expert.

for more info see:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

if you absolutely must roll your own(or you are on windows and need something that is compatible with windows php), use some variant of crypt like what i use for devving on windows:

```
function generateHash($plainText, $encdata = false) 
{ 
    $strength = "08"; 
    //if encrypted data is passed, check it against input
    if ($encdata) { 
        if (substr($encdata, 0, 60) == crypt($plainText, "$2a$".$strength."$".substr($encdata, 60))) { 
          return true; 
        } else { 
          return false; 
        } 
    } else {     
        //make a salt and hash it with input, and add salt to end 
        $salt = ""; 
        for ($i = 0; $i < 22; $i++) { 
        $salt .= substr("./ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789", mt_rand(0, 63), 1); 
        } 
        //return 82 char string (60 char hash & 22 char salt) 
        return crypt($plainText, "$2a$".$strength."$".$salt).$salt; 
    } 
}
```

using this is fairly straightforward.

to hash a password do it like so

`generateHash($password);`

to check a password against a hash(such as the stored hash in a database for a user)

`generateHash($password,$storedhash);`

edit to generate a random password try this:

```
function generateString() {
    $string = "";
    for($i=0; $i < 44; $i++) {
        $x = mt_rand(0, 3);
        switch($x) {
            case 0: $string.= chr(mt_rand(97,102));break;
            case 1: $string.= chr(mt_rand(65,90));break;
            case 2: $string.= chr(mt_rand(48,57));break;
            case 3: $string.= chr(mt_rand(103,122));break;
        }
    }
    return $string;

}
```

Comment: I think OP wants to generate password, not password hash :)

Comment: Also, `$2a$` is deprecated in favour of `$2y$` and it's recommended to use `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` or similar function to generate the salt.

Comment: you cant use openssl on windows. it results in the script executing until maximum execution time is reached(or it did last time i checked).

Comment: Then your installation is b0rked, OpenSSL works fine on Windows.

Answer (score -2):

There are many way to do this but I found a very simple method which can generate strong password of any length. This method is based on str_shuffle() function which randomly shuffles a string.

```
<?
    function generate_password( $length = 8 ) {
       $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()_-=+;:,.?";
       $password = substr( str_shuffle( $chars ), 0, $length );
       return $password;
    }
?>
```

To generate random password simply pass the desired length of password in this function. If you omit length parameter then it will generate 8 character long password by default.

```
$password1 = generate_password(); // default length 8
$password2 = generate_password(6); // 6 character long password
```

---

`generate_password()` is simple but,
If you want to strong password then try to Hashing algorithm for it.

You could add a key to your hash and send the timestamp with the query, e.g.:

```
$time = time();
$hash = md5($key . $time);
```

you can also use `hash_hmac()`:more detail [<kbd>LINK</kbd>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php)

```
$password = hash_hmac('sha256', $username . time(), 'secret');
```

Comment: `str_shuffle()` uses `rand()` internally, so I wouldn't suggest using this.

Comment: ya also use this bt also `mt_rand()` is good one.but is better on integer value.

Comment: Don't use `str_shuffle()` to generate passwords. If your input string contains each character only once, the resulting password will use each character only once, providing a very low entropy value. Also, note that `mt_rand()` is also a poor choice for cryptographic use. Use `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` instead. See note at http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php#refsect1-function.mt-rand-notes

Comment: Your $chars contain vowels.  If you do not remove the vowels, then your password will contain selatious words and phrases, and cursewords.  Also, you state this is "strong".  This is not a "strong" password because of what @QuinnComendant mentioned about your resulting password containing each character only once.